# How can I make this Google Sheets scheduling system work?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am creating a scheduling system for my company. I have tried this a few ways and I am not getting anywhere. I need the corresponding date that an employee is off to show "`TRUE`". Since I am using `VLOOKUP` for this, I am only getting the first value. I am using the following formula in cell F2.

```
=arrayformula(ifna(if(vlookup($E2:$E62,$A$2:$C$15,2,false)=F$1:L1,true,""),""))
```

I have highlighted the issue. Can someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

Sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7b2aiGRH9Mm2mB2A_d4uavXQeCKrW3vXgMcnYtAfRM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

use in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, QUERY(QUERY({A2:B}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"),
 "select Col1,Col3,Col5,Col4,Col2"), {2, 3, 4, 5}, 0))), TRUE, ))
```

[image]